# Google drive upload and Download in service as background

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am able to upload to google drive using accounts added in  Android phone .I followed  steps as told in  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ied1CjJ0iP0 . What i actually want to do is to upload to a single account from multiple phones via a service as a background  process .How can i do it .

Answer (score 0):

I did this by first logging in using the normal method from my fragment

```
    private fun upload() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Start sign in")
        val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .build()
        val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this.requireActivity(), signInOptions)

        startActivityForResult(googleSignInClient.signInIntent, MyFragment.REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            MyFragment.REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN -> {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                 Log.i(TAG, "Signed into drive ok.")

                 //Create an intent for starting the service
                 //Add whatever data you need to the intent
                 val intent = Intent(context, UploadService::class.java)
                 requireContext().startService(intent)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in the UploadService

```
override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    if (intent == null) {
        return
    }

    val lastSignedInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Not logged in")
    val driveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(this, lastSignedInAccount)
    val driveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(this, lastSignedInAccount)

    .... Do what you need to do here
}
```

Remember to add the service to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service
        android:name=".UploadService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```